# Theano cannot compile correctly in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, theano

For University work we are using Theano to look into Deep Learning, on the Lab computers we have a custom environment for using Theano.

Having copied this environment onto my local machine, I get this error when attempting to import Theano:

```
import theano

x = theano.tensor.fscalar()

C:\Labs\theano\python.exe C:/Users/Jack/PycharmProjects/untitled5/MAIN.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jack/PycharmProjects/untitled5/MAIN.py", line 3, in <module>
You can find the C code in this temporary file: c:\users\jack\appdata\local\temp\theano_compilation_error_bduwx3
    import theano as th
  File "C:\Labs\theano\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Labs\theano\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from theano.compile.mode import *
  File "C:\Labs\theano\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Labs\theano\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 674, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Labs\theano\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 140, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "C:\Labs\theano\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2396, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
. 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Some of my friends have copied the same environment onto their local machine and they are able to run Theano without error.

I have tried creating new virtual environments using anaconda and installing Theano in a fresh environment and still receive this error. Am I missing any required libraries or is there something that I'm not doing in PyCharm to allow it to use Theano correctly?

Comment: Have you tried following this tutorial (first hit on google): https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5348

Comment: PyCharm is just an IDE, it doesn't compile anything or affect how Python's module system works in any way. That being said, have you set the Python interpreter for your project correctly?

Comment: Haven't tried that tutorial, I followed the one on the Theano website for getting Theano installed on Windows. Will try that thanks!

Comment: I have set up the interpreter correctly, pointing it to the one that I copied from the Lab computers, even setting up a new environment with a clean interpreter still doesn't work .